# ServiceStack Service which has a Stream in its request breaks metadata page

Tags: c#, servicestack, metadata, .net-core

When I create a simple ServiceStack service with a Stream in the request, I find that I am unable to access the metadata page for the service method.

The service itself appears to work (I can send a stream to http://localhost:12345/uploadStream using PostMan and I can deserialize the stream in the service method OK with a bit of extra code.)

I am using .NET Core and Servicestack...

Complete repo:

```
using Funq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Web;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceStackCoreTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:12345/test/")
                .Build();
            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){ }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
            app.UseServiceStack((AppHostBase)Activator.CreateInstance<AppHost>());

            app.Run((RequestDelegate)(context => (Task)Task.FromResult<int>(0)));
        }
    }

    public class AppHost : AppHostBase
    {
        public AppHost() : base("Test Service", typeof(Program).GetAssembly()){ }

        public override void Configure(Container container){ }
    }

    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public TestResponse Any(TestRequest request)
        {
            return new TestResponse();
        }
    }

    [Route("/uploadStream", "POST", Summary = "Upload stream")]
    public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>, IRequiresRequestStream
    {
        public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestResponse{ }
}
```

My complete csproj (I am using Windows 10 / VS2017)...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Core" Version="1.0.40" />
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.Kestrel" Version="1.0.40" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I browse to the metadata page, I can see the list of operations, but when I click on 'XML', 'JSON' or 'JSV' next to the 'TestRequest' method, I get an error `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` in chrome (Edge reports nothing), and in my output window, I see `Exception thrown: 'System.MemberAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll`. Oddly enough, clicking on 'CSV' gives me a metadata page.

Am I creating the service method incorrectly in my ServiceStack project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET Core package had an issue where wasn't able to create an instance of an abstract class (Stream) which should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/b9cdf9c1527d6fc9e09a2e9aed5185b40920134e).

This change is available from **v1.0.41** `*.Core` packages that are now available on NuGet.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you (once again!) for your help. I've marked this as the answer but I'll only get round to testing this when I am next back at work next week.